# Usage of "resort to"

Tags: phrase-usage

"Former President Barack Obama encouraged Kenyans to fully embrace the promise of democracy by accepting the results of their forthcoming presidential election —without **resorting to** violence."

Can it be changed to "without **resort to** violence"？

Looked up in a dict. "Resort" can be used as a noun word: "There are hopes that the conflict can be resolved without resort to violence."

Looks like resort can be either used as a noun or a verb in this context. Is "resort to violence"="resorting to violence" true in this context？ If yes, will the meaning be the same as well?

Comment: You certainly *can* use ***resort*** as per your example (see [this MW definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/without%20resort%20to)). But the fact that you asked the question at all suggests you're already aware that [it's a declining usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=without+resort+to%2Cwithout+resorting+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithout%20resort%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwithout%20resorting%20to%3B%2Cc0) (particularly in AmE). So I'd avoid it if I were you, and stick with ***resorting***.

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I'd definitely say "resorting." "Resort" sounds totally wrong to my ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both can be used with the same meaning. Even though *resorting* is the more common phrasing.

Note, however:

> I **will** never **resort** to violence.

In this example, *resort* is the only variation of the word that can be correctly used. The context can make a big difference.

There is also a point of style to be made about the original sentence:

> Former President Barack Obama encouraged Kenyans to fully embrace the promise of democracy by **accepting** the results of their forthcoming presidential election —without **resorting** to violence."

Although it would not be wrong to use *resort*, it flows better if the verbs take the same *ing* (gerund) form.

Answer (score 2):

You could use either, but note they express different tones

> Hope to find a solution without **resorting** to violence

or

> Hope to find a solution, using violence only as a **last resort**